# I can't found buildscript in build.gradle

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, build.gradle

I know that `android\build.gradle` includes buildscript. but `build.gradle` in my project doesn't have buildscript. so I can't solve the following error.

```
C:/Users/JG-H/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ae0bf9da71bed198914dc960cb2262f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
                                                   .
                                                   .
                                                   .

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update C:\Users\JG-H\Desktop\Flutter practice 2024\02.little                               │
│ spicy\weather_app\android\build.gradle:                                                    │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                    │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

how can I find buildscript in `build.gradle`? The following is my buildgradle:

```js
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have copied buildscript in my other project.
but it can't be run.

Comment: This looks like your top level buikd.gradle, generally there are 2. The other one can probably be found inside of android/build.gradle.

Comment: ah.. i'm sorry.  the code in my question is in android\gradle\build.gradle...

Comment: odd, so for a flutter project I work they are like this:

flutter-app/android/build.gradle
&&
flutter-app/android/app/build.gradle

you can check both of these, if you can't find it you could add it manually to the flutter-app/android/build.gradle at the top above `allProjects {`

Answer (score 2):

I after the new upgrade of flutter 3.19. some change happen in android folder. you can find detail in this link https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply  or https://medium.com/@iam.umairimran/flutter-app-migration-guide-updating-to-flutter-3-19-0-ab8b66008838 .  buildscript not exist anymore in in build.gradle . also you need to upgrade user gradle. then `flutter clean` . `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 1):

I found it at location:

```bash
<project>/android/settings.gradle
```

and change the command line:

```bash
# id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me replacing the version in the file >/project_name/android/settings.gradle under plugins
org.jetbrains.kotlin.android version to 1.8.20
Your plugin should look like:

```
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.20" apply false
}
```

Ps: I've tried 1.19.x versions it didn't work